# Использование службы Windows для получение данных с интернета

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Написал службу, планировал использовать ее для подгрузки xml с гисметео.

```
protected override void  OnStart()
    {
        string pathToFile = "D:\\ServceFile.txt";
        List<string> s = getWeather();
        CreateFile(pathToFile);
        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathToFile);
        sw.WriteLine(s[0]);
    }

protected override void  OnStop()
        {
            string pathToFile = "D:\\ServceFile.txt";
            List<string> s = getWeather();
            CreateFile(pathToFile);
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathToFile);
            sw.WriteLine(s[0]);
        }

public static List<string> getWeather()
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load("http://informer.gismeteo.ua/xml/33345_1.xml");
        XmlNodeList list = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("TEMPERATURE");

        int i = 0;
        string[] strs = new string[4];

        foreach (XmlElement node in list)
        {
            strs[i] = node.GetAttribute("min");
            i++;
        }
        temp.Add(strs[0]);
        return temp;
    }
```

При запуске - файл создает, но ничего туда не записывает.
При остановке выбрасывает ошибку: возможно внутренняя ошибка службы, либо ошибка Windows.

В чем состоит проблема и вообще можно ли с помощью службы получать данные с интернета:?

Comment: Залогируйте ошибку, `stacktrace` и добавьте их в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: код ошибки неплохо бы привести. 5?

Answer (score 1):

дело в том, что вы открываете StreamWriter - это открывает документ для записи. но документ не закрыт и продолжает быть в открытом состоянии. Поэтому когда сервис останавливается вы пытаетесь еще раз открыть документ что приводит к ошибке. Вам нужно поработать над принципами создания самих сервисов.

Советую создать таймер при запуске сервиса, который будет вам обновлять состояние погоды в его обработчике, а также следите за сбоями, чтобы если что, то сервис не был обузой для компьютера и просто останавливался. После остановки сервиса высвободите таймер и также желательно учесть тот факт, что загрузка может занять некоторое время (хотя это вряд ли в вашем случае).